# JavaScript Timer clearInterval complications

Tags: javascript, timer

So I'm attempting to make a Pomodoro Timer without using an API (I know, stupid choice) but I feel as if I'm over-complicating this issue.

I forked my CodePen so I could post the current code here without confusing anyone. [My Code Pen](http://codepen.io/dnorthrupva/pen/rOBEEV?editors=001)

To see my issue: Just set Timer to .1 and Break to .1 - You'll see the Start to Resume works fine, but the Resume to start has issues.

I built in consoleLogs to track it and I see the Work Timer TRIES to start but then breakTimer over-runs it, and duplicates on every pass.

Why isn't my clearInterval working?

Things I've tried:
Adjusting names of clearInterval,
Setting it so it goes back to startTimer instead of start
force quitting it (instead of looping it back to startInterval.

The function is virtually identical to my startFunction yet fails to work properly. Would appreciate any input (I'm new to clearInterval but I believe I am using it right.)

```
  function breakTimer() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('visibility', 'visible');
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log("Break Timer...");
    breakTime--;
    if (breakTime < 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      working = false;
      start();
    } else {
      showTime(breakTime);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Edit**:

To answer the reply:

```
function start() {     
    if (working == true){ //This keeps it from being spammable
        return;
    } //Else
        workTime = $('#work').val()*60;
        breakTime = $('#break').val()*60;
        working = true;
        checkStatus();    
        timer = startTimer();
}
```

Unsure if I should post every Function here

Comment: you're not setting `timer` anywhere in the `breaktimer` snippet you posted, shouldn't it be `timer=setInterval(function () {//...`

Comment: Edited above post - Didn't post every function since it'd become a mess, and I linked the CodePen

Comment: Your codepen link seems to be broken @DNorthrup

Comment: @DNorthrup: Posting every function is obviously not a good idea. But posting incomplete code is also wrong (not just bad, wrong). You're supposed to post the smallest **working** code sample that demonstrates your problem. The advantage of that is that 90% of the time, getting your code to be the smallest example of your problem will make you realize what your problem is so you wouldn't even have to post here on SO for a solution because you'd find it yourself. But if you want to post here on SO you still should do the minimum working example thing.

Answer (score 0):

As per definition, the value returned by `setInterval(...)` is the ID of the created timer. As such, with your code you can only stop the last created timer because the ID in the `timer` variable gets overwritten, causing it to lose control over the previously created (and still running) timers.

The ID is what you pass on to `clearInterval(...)` to stop a timer. You will have to do this in a different way. You may ask for a different way in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/